# Is this an example of a mixed metaphor?

Tags: sentence, context

Is the writer employing a mixed metaphor here?

> A part of her was sinking languidly down into the passive pleasure of having returned to the familiar—**like a pebble**, she had been picked up and hurled back into the pond, and sunk down through the layer of green scum, through the secret cool depths to the soft layer of mud at the bottom, sending up bubbles of relief and joy. A part of her twitched, stirred **like a fin in resentment**: why was the pond so muddy and stagnant? Why had nothing changed? She had changed—why did it not keep up with her?

Comment: It's mixed. Also there's a comma missing after *fin*: _A part of her twitched, stirred like a fin, in resentment..._ Either that, or we also have a very odd case of anthropomorphism—a resentful fin?

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat— Thanks. I, however, don't think a comma is needed _there._ It probably reads: _A part of her twitched, [**and that part also**] stirred like a fin in resentment._ Just the case of an ellipsis.

Comment: It's more plausible that she twitched [ ] in resentment than that the fin was in resentment. What does that even mean?

Comment: I see no ***metaphors*** here. Just a couple of ***similes*** - which represent more or less *separate* references, so even if they were actually "metaphors", they wouldn't be "mixed", because they're effectively ***independent***.

Comment: @Fumble Fingers— I suppose the IMHO**sharp distinction** between **similes** and **metaphors** is of lesser relevance here than the **precision** of images and symbols invoked by the writer. Then too, a **metaphor** is, after all, an **implied simile.** But I'm sure you do find it jarring too to have a writer impose on you his or her digressive jaunts. That is poor art, IMHO.

Comment: I can't say I have a strong opinion about the quality of this *particular* text, but I can say that you're *completely* mistaken if you think that there's something fundamentally wrong with making figurative references to both "pebbles" and "fins" in the same paragraph. They're effectively *independent* elements, that just happen to have some similarities. We are after all talking about a writer who's [*been shortlisted for the Booker Prize three times.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anita_Desai) So given you don't even know what a mixed metaphor is, I'd tone down the criticism! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It's an honour to learn something from people like yourself. Point well taken, Sir! :)

Comment: I do however agree with Edwin Ashworth that _the sudden metamorphosis from pebble to fish sounds comically contrived._ And that's what I found off-putting too.

Comment: By way of being intentionally punny, I will say it's possible *Anita Desai* is out of her depth with the riparian references. I just searched Google Books to find that no other published writer has ever used the sequence "stirred like a fin" (which sounds like something out of *Jaws* to me! :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would describe it as a failed attempt at an [extended metaphor](https://literarydevices.net/extended-metaphor/).

It is certainly mixed in the sense that pebbles don't have fins.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too (the last line of your answer!) Thank you, @chasly!

Comment: Yes; there's been a question where an attempt to pin down the usage of 'mixed metaphor' ('My Tiddles is a tiger'? 'That lion's a tiger'? 'A lavendar bluebell'? Obviously, 'If there's a spark of pity in your heart, water it and make it grow' is an archetypal example. But whatever you call it, OP's example would be better rephrased. / I agree with your diagnosis.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth— So it's a badly contrived _extended metaphor_? And not a _mixed metaphor_ in the strict sense of the term?

Comment: I'd say so; the vehicles are all related (pebble ... pond ... green scum etc) but the sudden metamorphosis from pebble to fish sounds comically contrived. You _could_ argue for a second related metaphor, but the first, extended one laps at its feet, so it's hard to suddenly switch from an 8-point (roughly) metaphor to a discordant one _with a related tenor_ (pebble/hurled/pond/sink/scum ... //// fish/fin). _However you analyse it_, 'mixed' (in a pejorative sense) is appropriate: it could be better.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Edwin Ashworth!

Comment: @405662 O-T, so I'll delete when I remember. 'Phrase Finder' is a fine source of idioms and other fixed phrases. 'Through New Eyes' by James Jordan is an analysis of Biblical metaphors /  'images' (exact representations) / proportional comparisons (Just as C does D if you're persistent in asking, A does B (though A may be far more willing than C). I'll admit, it's on my 'to-do list'. There are various books of English proverbs, the Oxford Dictionary of Idioms (2 vol) (including 'phrasal verbs'), books on general 'sayings'.

Answer (score -1):

There are many many figures of speech.

But "like" is a "simile" and **simile** describes something as being **similar** to something.

It directly gives information to the readers to let them know how something can be similar to something.

For mixed metaphor, you can access here : https://www.grammarly.com/blog/metaphor/

Comment: Thank you, but that was not exactly what my question was about.

Comment: Please look at other questions on ELU discussing 'similes'. The definition of 'metaphor' generally accepted and used on ELU is a broader (and ultimately more useful) one than that taught in many schools. 'Similes'  (constructions using 'as ... as ...', 'like a ...', 'similar to ...', 'can be seen as corresponding to ...' etc, merely different in form (they _clearly indicate_ that a comparison is in play) from correspondences where the 'like a' etc is dropped (John is like a tiger → John is a tiger), are subsumed as a subset of metaphors. Here, John = tenor; tiger = vehicle.

Comment: Did you want to address the issue of whether the image is mixed or consistent?